# Issue using springframework taglib in a jsp while developing on jdeveloper

Tags: spring-mvc, oracle-adf, jdeveloper, weblogic12c

I'm developing a simple application using springframework. 
Used the below taglib in my jsp:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
```

application build always fails with error:

```
No tag library could be found with this URI. Possible causes could be that the URI is incorrect, or that there were errors during parsing of the tld file.
```

My application's `pom.xml` referring to the spring libraries so ideally we should be seeing this error. I'm not able to bring this application on the jdeveloper's integrated weblogic server. I'm no java expert but in great need of help to try to get this to work somehow.

We are trying to build a web application using spring web mvc framework and deploy to JCS. Requesting your inputs on this. Please let me know if you have faced an issue while trying to build something similar or if you have an idea on the technical feasibility of achieving the same using JCS.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5417442/jstl-support-in-weblogic

Comment: Hi philip - i think putting in the jars in the WEB-INF/lib folder is not necessary right ? I remember reading somewhere that when the URI is in the form of a URL, it finds the taglib within the referenced libraries. I have all the spring jars referenced by the application but still facing the issue. I tried the solution suggested - placed the spring-web-mvc jar in the WEB-INF/lib folder and modified the web.xml to reference the taglibs. still nothing works. spring-webmvc-4.2.2.RELEASE. any inputs pls

Answer (score 0):

In JDeveloper open the project properties and look under JSP Tag Libraries.
You probably need to add the spring tag library there.